# Using DB inside Laravel .blade files is secure?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Laravel is a secure php  framework following MVC pattern design .

But it's a question for me if i use Model codes like `DB::` class inside `.blade` files , is it secure or not ?

I know it's not good idea disturb MVC rules

But I want to test Laravel security.  If anybody did this action what security problems would happen?

Comment: leaking query language/builder into a template is usually something you dont want to do. you're controller should call a service / repo that fetches the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as secure/insecure (depending on your implementation) as in any other part of the framework. But no, it's not a good idea. You named MVC. Your template file (.blade) should receive data, not fetch it.

Comment: thanks . it's not good idea but it's a question what is secure problem if i do this action ?

Comment: There basically shouldn't be a security issue then. If you implement it just the way you would do it in your controller (securely) for example, it's fine in theory. It's just wrong.

Comment: Thanks .  so if i use database codes inside my .blade files i will not have security problem ?

Comment: I don't know your code. Using PHP in your blade file is basically the same as using PHP in your controller. If your queries are secure in your controller, then they are also secure when being executed in the blade file.

Comment: If we consider `controller` codes is secure enough , so can we use the same codes in `view` without problem ?

Comment: Just don't even entertain the thought of running queries in your view files. There is always a better approach. It's not a question of security, the code is run on the server whether in a view, controller, trait, model, whatever. Focus on what MVC offers, that is separation of concerns.

Comment: In general: yes. But what @DigitalDrifter said.